# Validate PHP captchacode By JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am running PHP scripts which generates captcha code in this way.

```
<img src="http://examle.com/captcha_code_file.php?rand=1846368456" name="6_letters_code" id="captchaimg">
```

I am using this code to grab rand value:

```
var src = a.src;
var match = src.match(/rand=(\d+)$/);
var rand = match.length > 1 ? match[1] : null;
```

I am having problem to compere this value 1846368456 with letters on my screen for Example AY231X. In other words these two values do not match. So is it possible to compere user inputs in form with rand value with JavaScript

Comment: want javascript to generate the same captcha by using a random generator?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you wondering how to compare a value in Javascript? Post some more code please.

Comment: WHY would you validate captcha via JavaScript? It makes it possible for someone to bypass captcha.

Comment: Bearing in mind captcha is generally there to stop bots and JS doens't run for bots, I can't see where this is going ... You might need to expand on your **end** goal to all of this.

Comment: @webnoob, JS runs fine for bots, avoid confusion with search engine spiders/bots

Comment: Ah yes, I was confusing them! Good point.

Answer (score 2):

Basicly, if you show your captcha image `captcha_code_file.php`, you generate a code to display.

Save this Code in the User Session. If your Form is sended, you check, if the captcha code is in the session.

The `rand=1846368456` parameter, is only to ensure, that you see the latest generated picture, and not some cached one.

**How to check the code from JS?**

You can provide an `checkCaptcha.php`, which basicly do the lookup in the session, and echo `true` or `false`. Before sending your Form, you can do an Ajax call to it.

checkCaptcha.php?code=foobar

```
$code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : '';
$sessionCode = isset($_SESSION['captchacode']) : $_SESSION['captchacode'] : '';
if (empty($code) || $code !== $sessionCode) {
    die('FALSE');
}
die ('TRUE');
```

Ajax:

```
var captchacode = 'foobar'; //Read from Input
$.get("checkCaptcha.php?code=" + captchacode, function( data ) {
    if (data == 'FALSE') {
        alert('Error with Captcha');
    }
});
```

On Form submit, you should clear the "used" captcha code.

**Whats about Security?**

We always check Captcha Code on Server side. This ajax is only for User Experience.

I don't think this solution provides a security hole.

It is more easy to do single Post:

```
$success = false

while(!$sucess) {
    $code = tryReadCode();
    $result = attackPageViaPost($code);
    $success = str_pos('Congrats, you successfuly entered the captcha', $result) !== false;
}
```

then

```
$success = false

while(!$sucess) {
    $code = tryReadCode();
    $success = getAjaxResult($code);
}

attackPageViaPost($code)
```

Comment: yes but can i check captcha code before sending, by JavaScript?

Comment: @ZeljkoKovacevic that is a bad idea. Captchas are usually used to prevent bots. If you provide a way for the bot to check the captcha on the client side (Javascript) people are going to find ways past it.

Comment: Yes i validate captcha code by PHP, but guy told me made also JS validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60034/discussion-between-ronni-skansing-and-christian-gollhardt).